# Why is this C# script causing lag spikes between the game objects being cycled in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've written a script in C# which cycles through game objects in a scene. It stores all of the game objects in a List, shuffles them so they are randomised and then activates them and deactives them with a defined delay. For some reason, it will randomly have lag spikes between the game objects being displayed. It sporadically takes longer than the defined delay set in the script to cycle between game objects. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to when the lag spikes occur, as far as I can tell. The script compiles and runs fine, displaying the behaviour I would expect except for this random lag. Any advice on how to optimise it so that there is no lag would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dolwhale : MonoBehaviour{

public List<GameObject> objects;
public int cycleCount = 10;
public float startDelay = 0.0F;
public float secsToWait = 2.0F;


// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Cycle());    
}

IEnumerator Cycle(){

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startDelay);

    for (int i = 0; i < cycleCount; i++){

        HelperFunctions.Shuffle (objects);

        foreach (GameObject current in objects){
            current.SetActive(true);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(secsToWait);

            current.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
  }
}


public static class HelperFunctions { 

    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list){

        int l = list.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            //pick new random index
            int random = i + Random.Range (0, l - i);

            //swap into new spot
            T newSpot = list [random];
            list [random] = list [i];
            list [i] = newSpot;

        }
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Firstly, are you sure it's this code? Secondly, how many objects? Thirdly, what's with the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(startDelay);`?

Comment: Also: If you're using Visual Studio as your IDE, have you tried profiling this code? That would tell you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @Emdot 

Is it possible that another script which I haven't written which is also being used in the scene is causing the lag spikes? The startDelay line is just to have some delay between running the code and the first object being activated in the loop. I am not using Visual Studio but apparently there is a profiler in Unity that I can use. Would you recommend that?

Comment: @Emdot As for how many objects, the code should be written so that it can adjust dynamically for the amount of game objects. The lag spikes occur whether you test it with 10 objects or 100.

Comment: With just 10 or 100 objects I suspect it's not this code--to my eye you're doing pretty much everything right. Do try commenting out the `yield`s, though--those are opportunities for other code to run, and if you're yielding too often that could be problematic.

Comment: When I remove/comment out the yields I get errors and the code doesn't work. It was my impression that you need to use a yield to preface a WaitForSeconds call but I am new to this. It says "cannot implicitly convert type 'Unity engine.WaitForSeconds' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'

Comment: Sorry, I meant removing the yield _lines_ rather than the yield _keywords_. I should have been more clear.

Comment: You might be better off by replacing the `foreach`, with a `for`. `foreach` will produce some garbage that needs to be cleaned at some stage. The Garbage Collector kicking in might be the "lag spikes" you're noticing? These lag spikes are noticeable in the Profiler? When you see a lag spike, it'll actually tell you if the GC kicked in or not.